# Disable VPN for a given process/application

Tags: windows-7, vpn, process

I'm using a constant VPN connection for privacy purposes. (I hate the laws, all the logging nowadays).

But when it comes to gaming, I don't really need encryption/hiding at all. I'd like to disable VPN for a  given process like Steam+Xy.exe to make a game playable.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

(OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64)

Comment: I was going to suggest using ForceBindIP but unfortunately it doesn't appear to be compatible with x64.

Comment: Damn it........ :(

Comment: I eat my words...

Comment: Fyi latest update/release of ForceBindIP is 2017.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [**ForceBindIP**](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) *(oh yes you can!)* and run your Steam+Xy.exe games using the following command from the command prompt:

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.0.1 "C:\Steam+Xy.exe"`

Note - you will need to change the IP address in the above command to be your normal default gateway and make sure the path to the application Steam+Xy.exe is correct.

This will ensure that traffic for your application bypasses the VPN and goes straight out through your default gateway and out onto the internet.

Simple modify your current shortcuts, whether they are in the Start Menu, the Programs folder or on your desktop to the above command for ease of use.

Comment: Update: It doesn't really work: http://noob.hu/2010/07/27/error.jpg

Comment: Hmm. A workaround - switch the metrics of the VPN connection and your primary internet connection so that everything goes out over your normal connection. Use ForceBindIP for everything else that you want to go out over the VPN. I'm sure someone will come up with an easier solution - would be interested to hear it myself!

Comment: Contacted the support of the VPN provider but even they don't know an answer yet. Tried many sites, hope someone will come up with a solution one day.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a little old, but if anyone is looking for a modern solution to this problem check out https://github.com/TunnlTo/desktop-app which is a Windows WireGuard client that allows application based split tunneling. It can also allow you to remove one particular application from the VPN connection as the original poster was asking for.